# How to label the time as "hh:mm:ss" on Kendo UI line chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I've created a demo as in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/condor05/dcmzapey/3/)

The code is also pasted below for your convenience.

```
var generateTrend = function() {
  $("#chart").kendoChart({
    xAxis: {
      labels: {
        template: "#:kendo.toString(value,'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss')"
      },
      title: {
        text: "Time"
      }
    },
    series: [{
      type: "line",
      field: "value",
      categoryField: "date",
      "data": [{
          date: new Date(2013, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0),
          value: 3
        },

        {
          date: new Date(2013, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0),
          value: 4
        }, {
          date: new Date(2013, 0, 1, 1, 3, 0),
          value: 5
        },

        {
          date: new Date(2013, 0, 1, 1, 4, 0),
          value: 7
        },
      ]
    }]
  });
};
generateTrend();
```

But currently the label on the x-axis is in the format of "hh:mm". However, what I need is "hh:mm:ss". Although I tried "template: "#:kendo.toString(value,'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss')"" in the code, it does't seem to work.

Would you please let me know the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `categoryAxis` instead of `xAxis` and close the expression with an additional `#`

See: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dcmzapey/4/)

Comment: thanks, That solved the problem. If I change the template alone, it won't work. I have to change both like you mentioned. So what is the difference between _categoryAxis_ and _xAxis_? I found it a bit confusing.